# Undefined offset PHP error, trying to read from file

Tags: php

I'm getting an "Undefined offset" PHP error, and don't get what causes it. I'm just a beginner.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 58
```

Here's code I'm using:

```
$file = fopen("portfolio.file", "r") or die("Unable to open a portfolio file.");
$portfolioFull = fread($file,filesize("portfolio.file"));
fclose($file);
$portfolioItems = explode(";", $portfolioFull);
$i = count($portfolioItems);
echo $i;
while ($i >= 0){
    $portfolio[$i] = explode("||", $portfolioItems[$i]);
    $i = $i - 1;
}
echo $portfolio[1][0];
echo $portfolio[1][1];
echo $portfolio[1][2];
echo $portfolio[2][0];
echo $portfolio[2][1];
echo $portfolio[2][2];
```

Here's what portfolio file contains:

```
Item 1 Title
||
Item 1 Description
||
DOWNLOAD PENDING
;
Item 2 Title
||
Item 2 Description
||
DOWNLOAD UNAVAILABLE
;
Test Item
||
Test Description
||
DOWNLOAD AVAILABLE
```

And here's what debug echo says: https://gyazo.com/2e1a6e90f1a33578b40e5f330e19dd78

Any clues how to fix that?

Comment: Could you point out which line is line 58?

Comment: Try running the loop like `while ($i > 0)` instead of `while ($i >= 0)`

Comment: @jaibatrik **Line 58:** `$portfolio[$i] = explode("||", $portfolioItems[$i]);`

Comment: @jaibatrik still nothing after changing to `while ($i > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = count($portfolioItems);
echo $i;
$i-- ; //reduce by one should fix the problem
while ($i >= 0){
    $portfolio[$i] = explode("||", $portfolioItems[$i]);
    $i = $i - 1;
}
```

Since the index of an array start from zero, the value of the last element will be `count($array) -1`.

In this case you are using the count value , which will be 1 greater than the last index. Ex: if array has 3 elements , the indexes  will be 0 , 1, 2 . Trying to use 3 as an index will give you this error.